# Сравнение символов Character в Java

Tags: java, if, char

Код должен сравнивать 3-ий символ строки с числом 3. Но почему условие неверно?
Я пробовал заменять `==` на `.equals`, но результат тот же.

import java.lang.Character. *;

```
public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
          String s = "123456";

        Character result1 = s.charAt(2);
        Character condition = 3;
      if(result1 == condition)   
      {
      System.out.println(result1);
      } 
      else {
        System.out.println("Сравнения не было");
           }

       }

    }
```

Comment: `Character condition = '3';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за коментарий, всё работает.

```
import java.lang.Character. *;

public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
          String s = "123456";

        Character result1 = s.charAt(2);
        Character condition = '3';
      if(result1 == condition)   
      {
      System.out.println(result1);
      } 
      else {
        System.out.println("Сравнения не было");
           }

       }

    }
```

Comment: а ещё лучше 
 char result1 = s.charAt(2);
        char condition = '3';